# jqGrid Does Not Insert Data Inside

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am trying to display some records from my database in a jqGrid in an asp.net MVC web project. The Grid UI with caption, column header and pager is resulted into my view except the data fetched from database.

Each of the records fetched from database table is used to make an Element object, definition is below:

```
public class Element{
    public string bid;
    public string user_id;
    public string name;
    public string queue_req_time;
}
```

Then all the Element objects are inserted into a List object and then converted JSON object by a method named UpdateData in Controller and returned:

```
public JsonResult UpdateData(){
    List<Element> in_queue_list = new List<Element>();
    // query command 'sql_command' is instantiated here.
    SqlDataReader reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read()){
        int iter = 0;
        user_id = reader.GetValue(iter++).ToString();
        bid = reader.GetValue(iter++).ToString();
        name = reader.GetValue(iter++).ToString();
        queue_req_time = reader.GetValue(iter++).ToString();
        Element temp_elem = new Element(user_id, bid, name, queue_req_time);
        in_queue_list.Add(temp_elem);
    }
    return Json(in_queue_list.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $.ajax({
                 url: "UpdateData",
                 method: "GET"
             }).done(function (result) {
                var result_x = JSON.stringify(result);
                console.log(result_x);
                UpdateGrid(result_x);
             });
         }

         function UpdateGrid(result){
             $("#jqGridTable").jqGrid({
                 datatype: "array",
                 colNames: ["User ID", "Code", "Name", "Request Sent At"],
                 colModel: [
                        { name: "user_id", index: "user_id", align: 'center' },
                        { name: "bid", index: "branch_id", align: 'center' },
                        { name: "name", index: "branch_name", align: 'center' },
                        { name: "queue_req_time", index: "queue_req_time", align: 'center' }
                 ],
                 data: result,
                 rowNum: 20,
                 rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                 gridview: true,
                 caption: "Waiting in Queue",
                 loadonce: true,
                 pager: "#jqGridPagerDiv",
                 loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                     //alert("Response Text \n"+ xhr.responseText);
                     alert("Status \n" + status);
                     alert("Error \n" + error);
                 },
                 loadComplete: function (data) {
                     alert("load complete with "+data);
                 }
                });
            }
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table id="jqGridTable"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
            <div id="jqGridPagerDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Data returned from "UpdateData" url is

```
[Object {bid="68", user_id="1068","name":"XYZ","queue_req_time":"5/15/2018 10:44:50 PM"}, Object {bid="1", user_id="1001","name":"NM","queue_req_time":"5/15/2018 10:45:02 PM"}]
```

And after stringyfying it is:

```
[{"bid":"68","user_id":"1068","name":"XYZ","queue_req_time":"5/15/2018 10:44:50 PM"},{"bid":"1","user_id":"1001","name":"NM","queue_req_time":"5/15/2018 10:45:02 PM"}]
```

And I am trying to load this stringyfied data.

Now The Grid does not display the received and processed data

---

**[Packages:1. jQuery.jqGrid-4.4.4 by Trirand ; 2. jQuery 3.3.1, All are installed from Nuget Package Manager]**

Comment: There are no `datatype: "array"`. You should use `datatype: "local"` instead. Alternatively you can remove `datatype: "array"` and `data: result` from jqGrid and to use `datatype: "json", url: "UpdateData"` without any additional `$.ajax` request. jqGrid will make Ajax call for you. Additionally the version 4.4.4 is **very old**. If you use NuGet then you should uninstall "jQuery.jqGrid" package and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.15.4 instead. Finally, it's better to use `ToString("o")` to return Date oi ISO format and use `formatter: "date"` in `colModel`

Comment: I was trying with datatype: array as it is documented [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data) that jqGrid supports array data, but yeah got to see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) to use datatype as local while doing client side data. Changed that to local, also directly used url with datatype- json, still does not load data. Only thing left is to upgrade the version

Comment: Changed the package to free-jqGrid (by Oleg Kiriljuk) 4.13.5. Loaded data from url directly. Thanks for mentioning the package name. But what is wrong with jqGrid 4.4.4?

Comment: jqGrid 4.4.4 is 5 and half years old. It's not supported since many years. I'm not sure how to interpret your last comment "Loaded data from url directly." Are the data loaded now successfully or not?

Comment: Data loading is successful. Version 4.14 and above are giving reference error in free-jqgrid.d.ts file. But 4.13.6 is not, therefore using this one. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm not sure why you get retro versions of free jqGrid too. The current version is 4.15.4. I provide the product for free and support only the latest version. The problem with reference error in `free-jqgrid.d.ts` in old versions is well known. I fixed it in later versions (see [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/353)). Please, use only **the latest** version of free jqGrid and the latest version of NuGet package.

Comment: But the latest version in nuget manager is 4.15.4 which also gives the reference error. That's why stayed with the old release.

Comment: What errors you get exactly? Do you use TypeScript or not? If you don't use jqGrid from TypeScript then you can just delete `free-jqgrid.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `datatype: "array"`. You should use `datatype: "local"` instead if you fill the input data with respect of `data` parameter.

Alternatively you can remove `datatype: "array"` and `data: result` options from jqGrid and to use `datatype: "json", url: "UpdateData"` *without* any additional `$.ajax` request. jqGrid will make Ajax call for you. Additionally the version 4.4.4 is **very old**. If you use NuGet then you should uninstall "jQuery.jqGrid" package and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.15.4 instead. I'd recommend you to read [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) as the short introduction of the usage "free jqGrid" fork of jqGrid. For example, the usage of [Font Awesome 4.x](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/) is strictly recommended.

Finally, it's better to use `ToString("o")` to return Date oi ISO format and use `formatter: "date"` in `colModel`.